# How to force Autosuggest to restrict addition to search result

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

Is there a way to make the jQuery Autosuggest plugin restrict users to only be able to actually add the the selection items that are included in the search results, but **not new ones** ?

I mean if I'm typing "joh" and the list shows "John" only, then I shouldn't be able to add "Johnny" to the selected items.

**Edit:** I'm using [wuyuntao](https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest)'s version. **You should check out [hlsolutions' one](https://github.com/hlsolutions/jquery-autosuggest) instead.**

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do it, but this is basically reverting everything Autosuggests does when an item is selected.

Add this to the options hash :

```
selectionAdded: function(elem) {
  var in_the_result_list = $.grep($('.as-results .as-list .as-result-item'), function(item) { return $(item).text() === elem.textNotChild() }).length;
  if (!in_the_result_list) {
    elem.remove();
    $('.as-input').html(elem.textNotChild());
    $('.as-values').val(function(i, current_value) {
      return current_value.replace(elem.textNotChild(), '');
    });
  }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this ?

PS : I'm using a custom jquery method to get the text of the element without the "x", feel free to achieve this the way you want. Here's the method if you need it :

```
(function ($) {
  function elementText(el, separator) {
    var textContents = [];
    for(var chld = el.firstChild; chld; chld = chld.nextSibling) {
      if (chld.nodeType == 3) { 
        textContents.push(chld.nodeValue);
      }
    }
    return textContents.join(separator);
  }
  $.fn.textNotChild = function(elementSeparator, nodeSeparator) {
  if (arguments.length<2){nodeSeparator="";}
  if (arguments.length<1){elementSeparator="";}
    return $.map(this, function(el) {
      return elementText(el,nodeSeparator);
    }).join(elementSeparator);
  }
} (jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a better and maintained version of the autosuggest plugin that already has this feature. Check this out : https://github.com/hlsolutions/jquery-autosuggest

Migrating from the old to the new one is pain-free. It's as simple as replacing the JS file.